# Как обновить маркеры в кластеризаторе ymaps3?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

У меня есть простая карта ymaps 3 с кластеризацией маркеров, при навигации по карте у меня на бэке реализован механизм выдачи точек по текущим bounds.

Собственно появилась необходимость удалять из кластеризатора точки, добавлять новые и обновлять кластеризатор.

Пока нашел только метод для его обновления
https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/ref/packages/clusterer/#update

Но ничего, связанного с удалением например текущих точек и добавлением новых. Прошу помощи!

**UPD:** Собственно update() и оказался тем, что мне необходимо, он принимает в себя YMapClustererProps
https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/ref/packages/clusterer/#YMapClustererProps

в котором можно передать features,
Однако при обновлении точек таким образом, я получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD2**: Мне подсказали с соседнего форума, всему виной моя невнимательность, ОДНАКО! Теперь clusterer.update() проходит без ошибок, но карта не обновляет метки, может нужно что то дополнительно?

Тут можно взглянуть на пример который я собрал
https://replit.com/@AlbertSaitov/TEST-YMAPS-3-UPDATE-CLUSTERER#script.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался благодаря участникам другого форума.
Обновить метки в кластере можно с помощью

```
    cluster.update({
      features: Feature[]
    })
```

Очень важно, чтобы id всех feature были уникальными и отличались от текущих feature, тогда Clusterer не будет их игнорировать при обновлении.

Демонстрацию работы можно посмотреть тут:

https://replit.com/@AlbertSaitov/TEST-YMAPS-3-UPDATE-CLUSTERER#script.js